# Dot is misplaced in markings along path

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I try to draw a diagram which represent the action of an homotopy. The dot is misplaced on the curve as you can see.
[image]
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \node[] (a) at (0,0) {};
    \node[] (b) at (4,0) {};
    \draw[thick] (a) to[out=50,in=150]node[above]{$f(x)$} (b);
    \path [postaction={decorate},decoration={markings,mark = at position 0.5 with {\fill[red] circle[radius=1pt];}}] to[out=50,in=150] (b);
    
    \foreach \o/\i in {40/160,30/170,20/180,10/190,-10/200, -20/210}
       \draw[dashed] (a) to[out=\o,in=\i] (b);
    \draw[thick] (a) to[out=-20,in=-130]node[below]{$g(x)$} (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a try: {\fill[red] circle[radius=1pt];}}] to[out=54,in=150] (b);

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro You're not solving the problem, you tweaked the coordinates so it looks like. Try to change `at position 0.5 with` to `at position 0.2 with` along with your modification and you'll see it doesn't fit.

Comment: I know! I write one comment not one answer.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro Then what is the purpose of writing a comment if you know that it does not work ?

Comment: I write:'Just a try' ... not the theorem of my life.

Comment: Your mistake is not using `(a)` as the starting point for the decorated path.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro I don't understand why anyone would upvote your ridiculous statement, probably people even more inexperienced than me on this site. To make it clear : You're not supposed "to try", the comment section is not a thought draft on which you can throw any embryo of an idea. You are not on a high school exam where writing false solutions is a possible way to score fraction of points. It's pretty simple, if you don't have the solution then you don't have to write down everything that comes through your mind.

Comment: But anyway, in the end my comment will probably be reported for being "too harsh" and telling an inconvenient truth for special people.

Comment: Your comment is only trivial. Because your question was trivial and generic. And I dont searched for upvote because I dont posted an answer. I post only a comment just to have your point were you want in any case. And now put your point were you want.

Comment: Your comments was only not polite in any case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't use `(a)` as the starting node of your decorated path:

```
\draw[thick] (a) to[out=50,in=150]node[above]{$f(x)$} (b);
\path[
  postaction={decorate},
  decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with{\fill[red] circle[radius=1pt];}}]
                 to[out=50,in=150]                    (b);
```

TikZ will assume `(0, 0)` here and the path is slightly different than the drawn one.

If you add `(a)` in front of `to` the dot will lie on the line again:

```
\draw[thick] (a) to[out=50,in=150]node[above]{$f(x)$} (b);
\path [
  postaction={decorate},
  decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with{\fill[red] circle[radius=1pt];}}]
             (a) to[out=50,in=150]                    (b);
%            ↑↑↑
```

---

You can just decorate the first graph directly and avoid this mishap in the future:

```
\draw[thick, mark with dot] (a) to[out=50,in=150]node[above]{$f(x)$} (b);
```

where `mark with dot` is

```
\tikzset{
  mark with dot/.style={
    postaction=decorate,
    decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with{\fill[red] circle[radius=1pt];}}
  }
}
```

This will place the dot at a slightly different place than the node `f(x)` because the node is placed at half the *time* of the curve where as the marking is placed at half the *distance* of the curve.

That said, a simple red dot can be placed along (the time of) a path with a

```
node[circle, fill=red, minimum size=+2pt, inner sep=+0pt]{}
```

and if it's not just a dot you can also use a `pic` (which can be placed like a node).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
  mark with dot/.style={
    postaction=decorate,
    decoration={markings,mark = at position 0.5 with {\fill[red] circle[radius=1pt];}}
  },
  mark with dot'/.style={edge node={node[circle,fill=red,minimum size=+2pt,inner sep=+0pt]{}}},
  mark with dot''/.style={every to/.append style={mark with dot'}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \node[] (a) at (0,0) {};
    \node[] (b) at (4,0) {};
    \draw[thick, mark with dot  ] (a) to[out=50,in=150]                 node[above]{$f(x)$} (b);
%    \draw[thick]                  (a) to[out=50,in=150, mark with dot'] node[above]{$f(x)$} (b);
%    \draw[thick, mark with dot''] (a) to[out=50,in=150]                 node[above]{$f(x)$} (b);
    
    \foreach \o/\i in {40/160,30/170,20/180,10/190,-10/200, -20/210}
       \draw[dashed] (a) to[out=\o,in=\i] (b);
    \draw[thick] (a) to[out=-20,in=-130]node[below]{$g(x)$} (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \node[] (a) at (0,0) {};
    \node[] (b) at (4,0) {};
    \draw[thick, mark with dot  ] (a) to[out=50,in=150] node[above]{$f(x)$} (b);
    
    \foreach \o/\i in {40/160,30/170,20/180,10/190,-10/200, -20/210}
       \draw[dashed, mark with dot] (a) to[out=\o,in=\i] (b);
    \draw[thick] (a) to[out=-20,in=-130]node[below]{$g(x)$} (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \node[] (a) at (0,0) {};
    \node[] (b) at (4,0) {};
    \draw[thick, mark with dot  ] (a) to[out=50,in=150] node[above]{$f(x)$} (b);
    
    \foreach \o/\i in {40/160,30/170,20/180,10/190,-10/200, -20/210}
       \draw[dashed, mark with dot''] (a) to[out=\o,in=\i] (b);
    \draw[thick] (a) to[out=-20,in=-130]node[below]{$g(x)$} (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

- [decoration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKHeB.png)
- [node (except the top one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZuk6.png)

Comment: Of course, any of the `mark with dot` styles can be parametrized to use, say, different colors without having to write a new style for each.

Comment: But (a) is precisely (0,0). So why doesn't it work at first. ?

Comment: @Flowt It isn't. `a` is a node with a border. For most path operations, TikZ chooses a point on the border of a node for the actual start/end point of a path (segment), not the `center` of the node. This is also the reason why all your lines don't start and end at the same point respectively. Add the option `draw` to the nodes `a` and `b` to see this better (and/or add any text to it). Maybe you don't actually want a node but a coordinate? Then do `\coordinate (a) at (0,0); \coordinate (b) at (4,0);` instead.

Comment: Or maybe a smaller node that's a dot, too. Say `\node[circle, fill, inner sep=0, minimum size=2pt] (a) at (0,0) {};`. You will still need to use `(a)`, though, but the diagram looks better than.

Comment: Thank you for the precision.